# Determine whether the MAC address is of a router or the destination computer?

Tags: ethernet, mac-address

In a given Ethernet frame containing the HTTP GET message can we tell apart whether the MAC address of the destination is of a router or end host?

The link to ethernet-ethereal trace :: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zdKxyxEz0zXVLX_GWVroZp58YPTuBxm3

Comment: Is it possible to guess that the mac is of a router using the infomation  from the whole trace?Since two different IPs(199.2.53.206(1st TCP protocol) & 192.168.1.1(1st ARP protcol's reply)) have the same mac address in trace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In a given Ethernet frame containing the HTTP GET message can we tell apart wether the mac address of the destimation is of a router or end host?

Not by the frame alone. However, if the destination IP address is local to the capturing host (=located within the same subnet) then the MAC address is that of the destination host. Destinations outside the host's local subnet require a router, so the destination MAC address will be that of the appropriate gateway.

If you've captured the frame through mirroring/SPAN please replace "capturing host" with "capturing port".

Of course, you can also use the MAC's OUI to make an educated guess which kind node is addressed. Many vendors build different device types though, so you might not be able to distinguish them.

*EDIT*: When examining a full (or rather lengthy) trace, you can also guess based on the ARP (or NDP) exchanges. Packets destined for local nodes and gateways require a previous ARP for the destination IP. Packets destined for remote nodes are encapsulated by MAC frames targeted for one of the gateways and there's no previous ARP for the destination IP itself. However, this is also possible using multiple IP subnets within the same L2 segment together with static ARP entries - not too common but possible.

Comment: Is it possible to guess that the mac is of a router using the infomation from the whole trace?Since two different IPs(199.2.53.206(1st TCP protocol) & 192.168.1.1(1st ARP protcol's reply)) have the same mac address in trace.

Comment: I've added that line of thought to the answer.

Comment: There is also the possibility of router forwarding on the same subnet Host1->R->Host2, for exotic reasons or more usually mistake.

Comment: @jonathanjo Good point - that would require a host configuration error / subnet mismatch though (not "the same subnet" for all nodes).

Comment: @Zac .. "believed to be same subnet" ... it's easy to look at one end and think they all have the correct/intended subnet mask.  Once it took me three days to find an evil misconfigured unit.

Comment: @jonathanjo I actually did build something like that in the days of yore. Long forgotten, fortunately...

Answer (score 0):

The MAC address is probably that of the router. The MAC address of the end host stays inside the boundaries of his LAN. What you do know is that if the end host isn't using some kind of proxy that the IP address in the packet is his, but you are talking about a frame.

If you think of the encapsulation/decapsulation process it will make better sense, since the network packet leaving from the end host's lan (through the router) is decapsulated from the MAC address (network OSI level).